# C# - Cannot implicitly convert type `string[]' to `string'

Tags: c#

Trying to take a string, split it by spaces, reverse it, and return the array values.

I have looked at other answers that say you can just return the array like this:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static string NameShuffle(string str)
        {
                    string[] strArray = str.Split(' ');
                    Array.Reverse( strArray );
                    return strArray;
        }
    }
```

But for some reason I am getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string

Comment: make return type `string[]`. public static string[] NameShuffle(string str)

Comment: your method saying that it returns string, but you are returning string[]. Either change. your method return type, or return a string from your method

Comment: *"Trying to take a string, split it by spaces, reverse it, and return the array values."* -- If you want to return "the array values", then you can't return a single scalar string.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Quick question about your comment. I am curious as to how you use the word "scalar" in this context; can you say a little bit about why you think of a string as a *scalar*?  I am always on the lookout for odd uses of jargon and how they evolve.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Context here is: a *scalar* is, as the word indicates, a value which *scales another value*.  "Double all the quantities in this recipe" for example gives a *scale factor* of two.  But you seem to be using "scalar" to mean something completely other than *scale another value by this value*; what do you mean by "scalar" in this context, and why?

Comment: A scalar in computer science just refers to a single value as opposed to an array or collection of values. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238033/what-does-it-mean-when-data-is-scalar

Comment: @ToddSkelton: Thanks; how odd that in 40 years of programming I have not encountered this usage of "scalar"! This usage is, frankly, a little weird but it seems to be widespread.

Comment: @EricLippert I think I encountered it first with ADO.NET's `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Yeah, I've really only seen the term used in "scalar-valued functions" in SQL Server.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, I meant "scalar" just as Todd indicated. I hadn't really thought about the origin of the term, and now that you point it out (scaling another value), it is a bit odd.

Answer (score 2):

Your return type on the method is `string` and it should be `string[]`

```
public static string[] NameShuffle(string str)
//             ^HERE^
{
    string[] strArray = str.Split(' ');
    Array.Reverse(strArray);
    return strArray;
}
```

if you need to convert it back to a string then do something like this

```
public static string NameShuffle(string str)
{
    string[] strArray = str.Split(' ');
    Array.Reverse(strArray);
    return string.Join(' ', strArray);
}
```